# How to predict data in aggregation for categorical ordinal variable in data mining with SQL developer?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, oracle-sqldeveloper, linear-regression, non-linear-regression

Categorical variables(Ex: Height:- Short,average,tall) are included in my data-set and need to find it with regression models in SQL developer.

Can I do it with SQL developer? or Are there any tools to find?